# get background drawable of view

Tags: android, android-view

The `getBackgound()` returns `BitmapDrawable`

```
Log.d(null,"drawable: " + v.getBackground());
```

How to get the drawable as R.drawable.xxx?

Comment: Do you want to know the ID of your Background resource?

Comment: I want to get the drawable that i assigned in my view. After creating background to my view by using this : setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.pic) - i want to get the value of R.drawable.pic... is it possible?

Comment: check my answer below. Hope it'll help you

Answer (score 3):

```
view.getBackgroundDrawable();
```

Use this to get the background drawable . This will return drawable

Edit

this working in versions below **jelly bean** , when this answer was written now this method is deprecated in latest versions

**New Edit**

For versions after jellybean try

```
 view.getBackground()
```

If someone wants to compare the drawables follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730731/get-current-background/27730795#27730795)

Comment: solution for jelly bean?

Comment: Try @msangel view.getBackground(). .Tell me if it works will update my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27730795/1450401

Comment: it does work, but the instance is kind of "new". comparing to existed the same palette give false.

Comment: are you trying to compare the drawable ?? i think if you are trying to do so please refer the link and it's comment i provide in comment .It explains why it's false ???

Answer (score 2):

View class does not provide that method, you can use:

`myView.setBackgroundResource(int resId);` **Receives the ID of the drawable you want to set**

but there is no getter of this method, only:

`myView.getBackgroundDrawable();` **Returns the drawable setted in the view.**

You can extend View to make your own one, and override setBackgroundResource, save the ID inside an auxiliar var, and then call super method. Define a getter to return the auxiliar var and you will get the function you want.

Comment: I have 2 buttons that have the same background drawable. but when i get their background drawable, it's different. what property will make them the same (aside from being a button)?

Comment: Two drawables objects, will not return true on equals I believe, but you can check its weight, or make your own buttons like I said to check the IDs

Comment: what do you mean check its weight?

Answer (score -2):

Any time you set the Background, set R.drawable.pic in a Drawable member class.

```
v.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.pic);
int myDrawable = R.drawable.pic;
```

Comment: `R.drawable.pic` is an integer value, not `Drawable`

Comment: had you tested getDrawable()?

Comment: The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int). and also what is intValue()?