# Get current background

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to get the current background to do a condition base on it.
For example, I have a xml with a next arrow, if the background=R.drawable.A, I want to change the background to R.drawable.B when next Button is pressed.

I defined my relative layout as follows :

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

if (rl.getBackground()== R.drawable.A){ //here the error
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
                }
```

The error is :
incompatible operands types int and drawable.
If there a way to get the current background and base on it do something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I don't know why they didn't override the `equals` method in the [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) class. So you should use [getConstantState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getConstantState()) method from the Drawable object that returns a [Drawable.ConstantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState.html) instance that holds the shared state of this Drawable to be able to compare it.

Kotlin

```
val drawableAConstantState = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.A)?.constantState
rl.setBackgroundResource(if (rl.background?.constantState == drawableAConstantState) R.drawable.B else R.drawable.A)
```

Java

```
if (rl.getBackground() != null && rl.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.A).getConstantState()) {
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
} else {
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.A);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,, but I tried this next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { if (rl.getBackground().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alef))){ rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B); } else { rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.A); } } }); But nothing happens when pressing it :( I dont know why

Comment: You are trying this code without any background at all in the first time. Am I right?

Comment: No I have the A background in the first time, Actually I am showing Alphabet each letter in a background for the same layout, and the next arrow has to show the next letter

Comment: Actually you have R.drawable.A for the first time. then the condition will not be true and usually do the else part every time. if (rl.getBackground().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.A))){ rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B); } else { rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.A); } and you should consider using switch case instead of nested ifs.

Comment: I tried it , it is okay for the null case only, so that the problem it does not know the : getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.A))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795626/arabic-indic-digit-android
hegazy can you help me in this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the background drawable is null or not like this:

```
if (rl.getBackground() != null){ 
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
 }else{
 // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to remedy the error just change it to:

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

if (rl.getBackground() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.A){ //<-- fixes the error
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
}
```

*a side note*: I suggest you check which drawable should be set against a logical component and not it's manifestation in the UI, but this is up to you.

Comment: Thank you,, but I tried this
       next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     if (rl.getBackground().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alef))){
         rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.B);
     } 
     else {
         rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.A);
     }
    }
   });

But nothing happens when pressing it :( I dont know why